# Android App to Google Analytics Packet Size

Tags: android, google-analytics, tcpdump, ports

I installed Google Analytics library in my Android App to persist the data to Google Analytics.

I'm trying to check how much information I'm sending to Google Analytics from my Android App. What is the size?

If there is a tool that I need to use, please give me some information about this.

I've tried to use `tcpdump`, but it seems to give the list of IP addresses and ports, but could not tell which is the application port, or how would I identify that it is the port I'm looking for to lead to the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that instead of finding out the port, I just needed to:

- find the IP Address of Android,
- find the destination IP address, and
- ping analytics.google.com to find out if the IP address of
  analytics.google.com almost match with the destination IP address.

Then, by filtering by IP address using Cocoa Packet Analyzer, I found out that the size is consistently 927 bytes, which is almost as big as 1KB.